# Lowercasing script in Python vs Perl

Tags: python, string, perl, file, lowercase

In Perl, to lowercase a textfile, I could do the following [`lowercase.perl`](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/lowercase.perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

while(<STDIN>) {
  print lc($_);
}
```

And on the command line: `perl lowercase.perl < infile.txt > lowered.txt`

In `Python`, I could do with `lowercase.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io
import sys

with io.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', 'utf8') as fin:
    with io.open(sys.argv[2], 'r', 'utf8') as fout:
        fout.write(fin.read().lower())
```

And on the command line: `python lowercase.py infile.txt lowered.txt`

**Is the Perl `lowercase.perl` different from the Python `lowercase.py`?**

**Does it stream the input and lowercase it as it outputs? Or does it read the whole file like the Python's `lowercase.py`?**

**Instead of reading in a whole file, is there a way to stream the input into Python and output the lowered case byte by byte or char by char?**

Is there a way to control the command-line syntax such that it follows the Perl STDIN and STDOUT? E.g. `python lowercase.py < infile.txt > lowered.txt`?

Comment: The Perl program basically streams, yes. If you run it without params, the loop will wait for input from the command line until you end the program or send `EOF`.

Comment: @alvas Python have `for line in sys.stdin:` which afaik will act the same as `while($line = <STDIN>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two interleaved issues here and I address that first. For how to make both Perl and Python use either invocation with a *very* similar behavior see the second part of the post.

**Short:** They differ in *how* they do I/O but both work line-by-line, and Python code is easily changed to allow the same command-line invocation as Perl code. Also, both can be written so to allow input either from file or from standard input stream.

---

(1)   Both of your solutions are "streaming," in the sense that they both process input line-by-line. Perl code reads from `STDIN` while Python code gets data from a file, but they both get a line at a time. In that sense they are comparable in efficiency for large files.

A standard way to both read and write files line-by-line in Python is

```
with open('infile', 'r') as fin, open('outfile', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(fin.read().lower())
```

See, for example, these SO posts on [processing a very large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669428/process-very-large-20gb-text-file-line-by-line) and [read-and-write files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604826/python-read-write-text-file).  The way your read the file seems idiomatic for line-by-line processing, see for example SO posts on [reading large-file line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python), on [idiomatic line-by-line reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343504/preferred-file-line-by-line-read-idiom-in-python) and another one on [line-by-line reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555468/how-should-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python).

Change the first open here to your `io.open` to directly take the first argument from the command line as the file name, and add modes as needed.

(2)   The command line with both input and output redirection that you show is a shell feature

```
./program < input > output
```

The `program` is fed lines through the standard input stream (file descriptor 0). They are provided from the file `input` by the shell via its `<`  *redirection*. From [gnu bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (see 3.6.1), where "*word*" stands for our "*input*"

> Redirection of input causes the file whose name results from the expansion of word to be opened for reading on file descriptor n, or the standard input (file descriptor 0) if n is not specified.

Any program can be written to do that, ie. act as a *filter*.  For Python you can use

```
import sys   
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.lower()
```

See for example a post on [writing filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589994/how-do-i-write-a-unix-filter-in-python). Now you can invoke it as `script.py < input` in a shell.

The code `print`s to standard output, which can then be redirected by shell using `>`.  Then you get the same invocation as for the Perl script.

I take it that the standard output redirection `>` is clear in both cases.

---

Finally, you can bring both to a nearly identical behavior, and allowing either invocation, in this way.

In Perl, there is the following idiom

```
while (my $line = <>) {
    # process $line
}
```

The *diamond operator* `<>` either takes line by line from all files submitted on the command line (which are found in `@ARGV`), or it gets its lines from `STDIN` (if data is somehow piped into the script). From [I/O Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk, and any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `"-"` , which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames.

In Python you get practically the same behavior by

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    # process line
```

This also goes through lines of files named  in `sys.argv`, defaulting to `sys.stdin` if list is empty.  From [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) documentation

> This iterates over the lines of all files listed in `sys.argv[1:]`, defaulting to `sys.stdin` if the list is empty. If a filename is `'-'`, it is also replaced by `sys.stdin`. To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to `input()`. A single file name is also allowed.

In both cases, if there are command-line arguments other than file names more need be done.

With this you can use both Perl and Python scripts in either way

```
lowercase < input > output
lowercase input   > output
```

Or, for that matter, as `cat input | lowercase > output`.

---

All methods here read input and write output line-by-line. This may be further optimized (buffered) by the interpreter, the system, and shell's redirections. It is possible to change that so to read and/or write in smaller chunks but that would be extremely inefficient and noticeably slow down programs.

Comment: Thank you for going way out to explain the differences and give examples!!

Answer (score 7):

Python 3.x equivalent for your Perl code may look as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line[:-1].lower(), file=sys.stdout)
```

It reads stdin line-by-line and could be used in shell pipeline

Answer (score 3):

Slightly off topic (depending on your definition of "Perl") but maybe of interest...

```
perl6 -e  ' .lc.say for "infile.txt".IO.lines ' > lowered.txt
```

This neither processes "byte by byte" nor "whole file" but "line by line". `.lines` creates a lazy list so you will not use a ton of memory if your file is large.  The file is presumed to be text (meaning you get `Str`'s rather than `Buf`'s of bytes when you read) and the encoding defaults to "Unicode" - meaning `open` will try to figure out what UTF is used and if it can't it will presume `UTF-8`. Details [here](https://doc.perl6.org/routine/open#Encoding_options).

By default line endings are `chomp`'ed as you read and put back on by `say` - if the processing requirements prohibit that, you can pass the boolean, named parameter `:chomp` to `.lines` (and use `.print` rather than `.say`) ;

```
$ perl6 -e  ' .lc.print for "infile.txt".IO.lines(:!chomp) ' > lowered.txt
```

You can avoid the IO redirection and do it all in perl6 but this *will* read the whole file in as one `Str`;

```
$ perl6 -e  ' "lowered.txt".IO.spurt: "infile.txt".IO.slurp.lc '
```

Answer (score 2):

*Is the Perl lowercase.perl different from the Python lowercase.py?*

The Python file takes filenames for input and output. The Perl file does streaming (e.g. may be used in `some_command | your_perl_script.pl | some_other command`).

*Does it stream the input and lowercase it as it outputs? Or does it read the whole file like the Python's lowercase.py?*

```
while(<STDIN>) {
```

walks through your input line by line. As long as your input contains \n (default line break, may be changed by [setting $/](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR)). This is streaming.

*Instead of reading in a whole file, is there a way to stream the input into Python and output the lowered case byte by byte or char by char?*

Probably yes, but I don't know Python :(

Answer (score 1):

In the example the only difference is how the data is accessed. One is by opening a file (the python version) the other is by [piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) i/o to the program (perl version). Either language can access the data by either method.

[Examples working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429966/how-to-make-a-python-script-pipeable-in-bash) with stdin/stdout in python:

Answer (score 1):

I see two questions here:

1. how to lowercase text without reading in an entire file: **Read it line by line**
2. how to handle commandline arguments and default to stdin if none: **Use `fileinput`.**

Here's how:

To lowercase text, just use `fin.readline()` or just iterate the file object (which reads one line at a time):

```
for line in fin:
    ...
```

To handle filenames specified on the command line, with `stdin` if none, use `fileinput`. If you'll just be sending everything to `stdout`, this will be enough:

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line.lower(), end="")
```

But if you want to lowercase a large corpus and store the result to disk, it's likely that you'll want to output each file separately. That's a little bit more work, since `fileinput` won't automatically redirect your output.  Here's one way:

```
currentname = None
for line in fileinput.input():
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
        if currentname and currentname != "<stdin>":  # clean up after previous file
            fout.close()

        currentname = fileinput.filename()        # Set up for new file
        if currentname == "<stdin>":
            fout = sys.stdout
        else:
            fout = open(currenttname+"-low", "w"
    fout.write(line.lower())
```

)

I wrote out each file `<name>` to `<name>-low`, but you can of course substitute any other approach (e.g., use the same name for output but in a different directory).

Answer (score 0):

The Python program will attempt to read the whole input file. The call of `read()` without an argument will read till EOF, see [the io module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase).

There is a small bug as well, `fout` should be opened in the `"w"` mode.

As mentioned by @denis-shatov, it is possible to write a Python script equivalent to the Perl one.